# Is there any way to resize an images present in an array of images

Tags: image-processing, keras, tensorflow2.0, numpy-ndarray

i have an image data present in format of (1449,640,480,3) i want to resize my images before giving it to CNN. i can resize them by extracting  every single image and then group them in an array but it would take alot of time and RAM. is there any way (using tensorflow, or keras or any other library ) to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```

I have just loaded the mnist library for giving example.
If we see the shape of the train_images.

```
train_images.shape
> (60000, 28, 28)
```

So its a 3D array where we have 60000 images with 28×28 shaped images. We can convert this 28×28 2D images to 1D images of 784(28×28).

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images.shape
> (60000, 784)
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: thanks for your help. but i want to resize my images. for example in mnist case can we resize them from (60000, 28, 28) to (60000. 20 , 20).

Comment: you mean (60000,28,28) to (60000, 20, 20) ?

Comment: yes. in my case (1449, 640, 480) to (1449, 304 ,228)

Comment: tr `cv2.resize(img_array, (img_size,img_size))`